# rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection closed in Go code

Tags: go, dgraph

I am working on `Dgraph` and `Go` integration.I am trying to access `Dgraph` query in `Go` and for that I am using `github.com/dgraph-io/dgo` library.

Here is the code :

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo"
    "github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/protos/api"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

func main() {

     query := `{
         people(func: has(name)) {
            name
           follows{
             name
           }
         }
     }`

     conn, err := grpc.Dial("x.x.x.x:8000", grpc.WithInsecure())
     if err != nil {
          log.Fatal(err)
     }
     ctx := context.Background()
     dgraphClient := dgo.NewDgraphClient(api.NewDgraphClient(conn))

     txn := dgraphClient.NewTxn()
     txn.Query(ctx, query)

     request := &api.Request{
          Query: query,
     }

     response, err := txn.Do(ctx, request)
     if err != nil {
          log.Fatal(err)
     }
     fmt.Println(string(response.Json))
}
```

I am getting error **rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection closed** when I an trying to run code.
As I am new to the `Go` and `DGraph Database` I have very limited knowledge.

Can anyone please help what exact changes need to be done to fix this error.

Comment: Did you check that the server is running, using port `:8000`, and reachable? Make sure you use the grpc port, not the http port. From the [docs](https://dgraph.io/docs/clients/go/), it looks like the default grpc port is `9080`

Comment: @Marc Yes I checked Server its up and running.I even run given query there and its giving response.

Comment: How is your dgraph setup?

Answer (score 3):

The service at the port 8000 is the UI only. If you wanna use gRPC you have to call it in the port 9080. Never 8080, 8000, 6080, and so on. Check this docs https://dgraph.io/docs/deploy/ports-usage/#types-of-ports

In this example https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgo/blob/a38d5eaacbf8667cc2d6e7b40bd0978cede4000f/examples_test.go#L35

It is using the port 9180. Cuz the Cluster for testing has an offset of 100. That means that all ports in the Alpha increases 100 ints. So, all ports in Alpha have to take into account the offset. The rest API is 8180 and the gRPC is 9180.

In the usual cases, you would never think about using offset when you are learning things. So you probably started a normal cluster. And the default port is 9080.

Answer (score 2):

As I met the same appearance with you, after one hour work, I discover the reason is I use a proxy like `export https_proxy=http://192.168.3.92:7890 http_proxy=http://192.168.3.92:7890 all_proxy=socks5://192.168.3.92:7890`,and while I execute `unset https_proxy http_proxy all_proxy`, it success!