# Google Cloud Run: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = last resolver error: produced zero addresses

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have an API hosted on Google Cloud Run. I'm not sure how to replicate this error, but it seems like during the first few pings after a while of inactivity, the API is down and I get the following error: `rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = last resolver error: produced zero addresses`.

After a few more pings, the API behaves correctly. I never get this error in development, so is this just a problem with Google Cloud Run?

Comment: Which language and version are you using with Cloud Run? It sounds like the service you are calling is temporarily unavailable for a short period during the deployment, and the failed attempt needs handling. It will be interesting to check the logs and post back here with any error messages: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting

Comment: Go 1.15. I thought for a while that Cloud run would hot swap the new build after it's built to prevent downtime, no?

Comment: I am not overfly familiar with Go but wonder with it is an issue with the code. Have you checked this similar case on Stack Overflow? They received a similar error message
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63372312/rpc-error-code-unavailable-desc-connection-closed-in-go-code